# Pandas, when saving to csv, year format in date gets cut off

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm exporting a CSV file using pandas:

```py
final_monthly_usage_report = pd.concat([self._construct_usage_data_csv(account) for account in accounts])

        final_monthly_usage_report[STARTDATE] = final_monthly_usage_report[STARTDATE].apply(
            lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
        final_monthly_usage_report[ENDDATE] = final_monthly_usage_report[ENDDATE].apply(
            lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

        final_monthly_usage_report[STARTDATE] = final_monthly_usage_report[STARTDATE].apply(str)
        final_monthly_usage_report[ENDDATE] = final_monthly_usage_report[ENDDATE].apply(str)

        # export it to csv file
        report_name = f'{self.CURRENT_YEAR}_{self.CURRENT_MONTH - 1}_usage_report.csv'
        final_monthly_usage_report.to_csv(report_name, index=False, date_format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

But when opening the CSV file, the year format is two digits instead of four (11/01/20):

```
STARTDATE,ENDDATE,
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
11/01/20,11/30/20,1
```

How can I prevent Pandas from changing the format? As the code shows, I tried specifying format and passing to str and specifying `date_format` when exporting.

Comment: Try opening the file in notepad and see if the date looks correct.

Comment: This looks like you opened the resulting file in Excel. Probably your file is fine, and Excel is just being Excel.

Comment: In pycharm itself and text editor, it does the same as well,

@tripleee 
adding screenshots

Comment: No, don't add pictures of text. Add the text itself. See also [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: added raw csv
@tripleee

Comment: _never_ use excel to view data you need see in a raw format. use notepad or a normal ide. Recently had a client who swore the acocunt numbers he gave me were entered into their datawarehouse incorrectly, although I assured him I read the raw data from the file (via the xml nodes in excel) turns out he was viewing it in Excel and it was removing the leading `0`s' for an account-number. big deal.